# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'bool' and 'Q'

Tags: django, django-q

I'm running Django 1.7 and I'm getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'bool' and 'Q'` when trying to do the following:

```
class PersonList(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "persons/list.html"
    model = Person
    queryset = Person.objects.filter(Q(field1__isnull=True | Q(field2__isnull=True)))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the example code, brackets are not where they are supposed to be when working with `models.Q`.

Solution:

```
Person.objects.filter(Q(field1__isnull=True) | Q(field2__isnull=True))
```

Mind the closing bracket.

Comment: It's funny. This question was closed because of a typo. But I'm glad Google led me here, because I had a very similar type (with 3 Qs instead of 2), so this was quite helpful. +1